# Sed recognizing only a portion of search pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking for a way to replace all the occurrences of a website in a file with a constant. I'm using `gsed` and regex on my mac (don't get deviated with the term mac, as this is the same output I'm getting even when executing on a windows machine) to accomplish this. I'm able to successfully validate the regex on regex101.com but sed substitution is failing for some reason

```
gsed --version : gsed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

`(g)sed` command:

```
find . -type f -path "./file1.txt"  -exec gsed -i -E -f /tmp/scripts/regex {} \;
```

`/tmp/scripts/regex` contents:

```
s/(ftp|http[s]?):\/\/([\w\.-]+)/\1{Your_Site}/gI
```

Sample `file1.txt` contents:

```
* "{\n \"firstName\": \"\",\n \"lastName\": \"\",\n \"street1\": \"\",\n \"street2\": \"\",\n \"city\": \"\",\n \"state\": \"\",\n \"postalCode\": \"\",\n \"country\": \"\",\n \"domain\": \"http://example.org\",\n \"action\": \"addUser\",\n \"token\": \"\",\n \"transId\": \"1413290890.usr.209883490\",\n \"customerId\": \"145qjk345kl_908jkl.345\",\n  \"src_name\": \"Your_Application\",\n \"channel\": \"webpage\",\n \"accountId\": \"0097892hjke6987hiuw.ACNT.hsapou8972rjk\",\n \"system\": \"Your_System\",\n \"originatingSystem_code\": \"Your_System_Id\",\n \"purchase_currency\": \"USD\",\n \"url\": \"https://another-link-to-my-example.org/add-user/new\",\n \"createFlag\": \"on\",\n \"web_version\": \"7\",\n
```

Expected output:

```
* "{\n \"firstName\": \"\",\n \"lastName\": \"\",\n \"street1\": \"\",\n \"street2\": \"\",\n \"city\": \"\",\n \"state\": \"\",\n \"postalCode\": \"\",\n \"country\": \"\",\n \"domain\": \"http://{Your_Site}\",\n \"action\": \"addUser\",\n \"token\": \"\",\n \"transId\": \"1413290890.usr.209883490\",\n \"customerId\": \"145qjk345kl_908jkl.345\",\n  \"src_name\": \"Your_Application\",\n \"channel\": \"webpage\",\n \"accountId\": \"0097892hjke6987hiuw.ACNT.hsapou8972rjk\",\n \"system\": \"Your_System\",\n \"originatingSystem_code\": \"Your_System_Id\",\n \"purchase_currency\": \"USD\",\n \"url\": \"https://{Your_Site}/add-user/new\",\n \"createFlag\": \"on\",\n \"web_version\": \"7\",\n
```

Current output:

```
* "{\n \"firstName\": \"\",\n \"lastName\": \"\",\n \"street1\": \"\",\n \"street2\": \"\",\n \"city\": \"\",\n \"state\": \"\",\n \"postalCode\": \"\",\n \"country\": \"\",\n \"domain\": \"http://{Your_Site}xample.org\",\n \"action\": \"addUser\",\n \"token\": \"\",\n \"transId\": \"1413290890.usr.209883490\",\n \"customerId\": \"145qjk345kl_908jkl.345\",\n  \"src_name\": \"Your_Application\",\n \"channel\": \"webpage\",\n \"accountId\": \"0097892hjke6987hiuw.ACNT.hsapou8972rjk\",\n \"system\": \"Your_System\",\n \"originatingSystem_code\": \"Your_System_Id\",\n \"purchase_currency\": \"USD\",\n \"url\": \"https://another-link-to-my-example.org/add-user/new\",\n \"createFlag\": \"on\",\n \"web_version\": \"7\",\n
```

Please ask for any additional info if I might have missed.

Comment: What if you use `s/(ftp|https?):\/\/[^\"]+/\1{Your_Site}/gI`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, your suggestion worked, so does rtx-13's. I would greatly appreciate if you can suggest why this negative conditioning worked but not the escape sequence. I can live with this answer but am curious to know when to use what and why some work and some don't so that I can use it wisely in my next works.

Comment: `[\w]` matches ``\`` and `w` in a POSIX BRE/ERE regex. It is not JavaScript.

Comment: Got it, Thank you @WiktorStribiżew are there any escape sequences at all in POSIX? Any references you can point to related to POSIX regex to learn?

Comment: It depends on which version you use. In GNU sed, you may use `\s` and `\w` outside bracket expressions. Only some chars should be escaped, and escaping differs between ERE and BRE. See [this reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html).

Comment: I found this sed manual @ https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html looks like this is the closest I could get in terms of the material. I'll start with this, please suggest any other reference material, if you can.

Comment: For sed, see https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: This works, Thank you @wiktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[:alnum:]` character class or similar instead of `\w` inside bracket expressions.

I've highlighted the change below:

```
s/(ftp|http[s]?):\/\/([\w\.-]+)/\1{Your_Site}/gI
                       ^^

s/(ftp|http[s]?):\/\/([[:alnum:]\.-]+)/\1{Your_Site}/gI
                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Please note that this RE is still too permissive and will match invalid names, in case that is of concern.

Comment: Thank you very much @rtx13, This change worked just like expected, I can't upvote to this answer but it worked perfectly for my problem. I tried various combinations but not this, Any possible explanation why this worked but not other conditions? If you can point me to any material or reference to update my knowledge and to know various possible alternatives to try before I can reach out for help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @srikanthreddy Bracket expressions (i.e. what can go between `[` and `]`) is somewhat limited.  Characters like `.` and `*` lose their "normal" regular-expression meaning.  The same is true for backslash escapes.  Some trivial ones like `\n` or '`\xNN` do work, but special escapes like `\w` or `\<` do not.  I'm not sure if this is clearly explained; have a look at `info sed` or https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html.

Comment: The section https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions starts with "_A bracket expression_ is a list of characters enclosed by ‘[’ and ‘]’. ...", and proceeds to state later on "The characters $, \*, ., [, and \ are normally not special within list. For example, [\*] matches either ‘\’ or ‘*’, because the \ is not special here. "

Comment: Got it, Thank You @rtx13